# Layered recording. How does it work?

Tags: animation

What is *Layered Recording* and how does it work? I didn't notice any changes between the checkbox turned on and off.

From the manual:

> Layered recording
> Adds a new NLA Track and strip for every loop / pass made over the animation to allow non-destructive tweaking.

[image: screenshot of checkbox layered recording]

Answer (score 0):

https://youtu.be/UMGRXU2k40Y

I got it to work for producing new NLA track/strip by playing through the animation, setting the auto keying, and then moving the cube. It tends to create them when keyframing around the end and start frame.